# What is the max theoretical total network bandwidth from switch\router

Tags: networking

My question is about the maximum bandwidth a switch\router can support for an entire network (not just 1 machine to another).

These pieces of equipment are often rated at 100 MBit, 1 GBit, etc.  However they often have at least 4 ports if not more.

Quoting from Wikipedia:

An Ethernet switch operates at the data link layer of the OSI model to create a separate collision domain for each switch port. *With four computers (e.g., A, B, C and D) on four switch ports, any pair (e.g. A and B) can transfer data back and forth while the other pair (e.g. C and D) also do so **simultaneously***, and the two conversations will not interfere with one another. In full duplex mode, these pairs can also overlap (e.g. A transmits to B, simultaneously B to C, and so on)

So if A is talking to B and C is talking to D at the same time through a 1 GBit switch, will each pair receive a 0.5 GBit connection or will each pair receive a 1 GBit connection?  If each pair is receiving a 1 GBit connection, then the total network bandwidth at that time is 2 GBit and then seems dependent on the number of ports available on the router as well as the number of machine pairs on the network.

Comment: This is actually answered in another question http://serverfault.com/questions/521389/are-network-switch-data-transfer-speed-limits-per-port-or-per-device?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Vendor's will label this as the fabric or backplane of the switch and is something you can generally find in the documentation/specs. If you are bored you can go read a [history of the term on etheralmind](http://etherealmind.com/what-is-the-definition-of-switch-fabric/).

Router's will often have other limitations such as packets per second and processing power when using things like ACLs.

Also keep in mind Ethernet is generally full-duplex, meaning it is 1G in and 1G out at the same time (they are independent).